# Error trying to migrate with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDUFF.png) Create a table in Laravel, when trying to migrate, this error occurs to me, someone can help me

[Error trying to migrate with Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLpkm.png)

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error
this question has been asked before, please do a bit of research before asking.

Comment: You should add more information like your migration etc

Comment: The ideas in your question looks a little bit disorganised. Please see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the data type of `email`?

Comment: Si encontré esa información laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error, pero no resolvio mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

try put in your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
 public function boot()
    {
        \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```